# Range Code no longer works with excel update

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I don't often update my excel because the usually break something instead of fixing anything. I wrote a macro to do some sorting that worked fine, then Excel forced the latest update now I am getting type mismatch errors all over the place that I can't fix. The current piece of code giving me problems is, I get a type mismatch on the range code.

```
    Cells(1, 26).FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(""sheathing"",C[-17],0)    
    i = Cells(1, 26)
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(LastRow, 17)).Cut
```

I have no idea how to fix it so don't know what to try

Comment: If there's no match then you can't use `i` as a row number.  Is there an error in Z1 ?

Comment: What is the value of i = Cells(1, 26)?

Comment: And what is LastRow?

Comment: The value in i = Cells(1,26) is what the match formula calculates, it does work and it does pull a value.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more robust:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet, m 'as Variant
Set ws = ActiveSheet
m = Application.Match("sheathing", ws.Columns("I"), 0)
If Not IsError(m) Then
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(m, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, 17)).Cut
Else
    'no match found
End If
```

Comment: there is no error in Z1. The range line of code

Comment: Still got as type mismatch error, there is a numerical value in Z1

Comment: My code isn't using Z1 so I'm not sure why that would be a problem?  I was guessing the use of Z1 in your posted code was only to perform the `MATCH()` to supply a value for the `Cut` operation.